# How to convert array into xml tag

Tags: php

```
Array([promo_code] => Array
        (
            [0] => promo_code is required
        )

    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => first name is required
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => last name is required
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => address is required
        )

    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => city is required
        )
);
```

I have above array and I want to show it as

```
 <?xml version=1.0?>
 <Result>
 <promo_code>promo_code is required</promo_code>
 <last_name>last_name is required</last_name>
 <address>address is required</address>
 <city>city is required</city>
 </Result>
```

Please guide thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert array to SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Comment: yes , I have tried , foreach loop with key and value

Comment: @Bhaveshvaghela that makes no sense considering the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the the [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class. You haven't tried anything , if you had there would be some code here.